# Retrieve Emails addresses in CSV file in Powershell via Get-ADGroup command

Tags: powershell, automation, email-address, get-aduser

Currently I have a script that I am able to interrogate an OU (which I define in the script) which shows Username, Name of the user, AD Group Name and the Description of that AD group into a CSV file:

```
$ou = 'distinguishedName of my OU'
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Properties Description | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($member in Get-ADGroupMember $_) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SamAccountName = $member.SamAccountName
            Name           = $member.Name
            GroupName      = $_.Name
            Description    = $_.Description
        }
    }
} | Export-csv C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

When I try to pull of the email addresses of the users as well in the same script I get an error.

```
$ou = 'distinguishedName of my OU'
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Properties 'Description', 'EmailAddress' | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($member in Get-ADGroupMember $_)  
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SamAccountName = $member.SamAccountName
            Name           = $member.Name
            EmailAddress   = $_.EmailAddress
            GroupName      = $_.Name
            Description    = $_.Description
        }
    }
} | Export-csv C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The error message states the script fails around this point of the script:

```
-Properties 'Description', 'EmailAddress'
```

Comment: Please show us the exact error message in full :)

Comment: Sorry I know missed the most important bit out. But Theos script worked below. Thanks for your assistance though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include the email addresses of the **users** you will need to take it one step further and call `Get-ADUser` foreach member in the group.
Snag is that `Get-ADGroupMember` can return not only users, but computer ad group objects as well, so you will need to filter those out.

```
$ou = 'distinguishedName of my OU'
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Properties 'Description' | ForEach-Object {
    $group   = $_  # just for convenience..
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember $_ | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' }
    foreach($member in $members) {
        $user = Get-ADUser $member -Properties EmailAddress
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SamAccountName = $user.SamAccountName
            Name           = $user.Name
            EmailAddress   = $user.EmailAddress
            GroupName      = $group.Name
            Description    = $group.Description
        }
    }
} | Export-csv C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

The LDAP Display Name for [the `E-mail-Address` attribute in Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-mail) is not `EmailAddress`, but `mail`:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Properties 'Description', 'mail' | ...
```

Comment: Tried this, it ran but didn't get the email addresses seems in the CSV.

Comment: @S.Mahmood Well, you'd need to replace the references to `EmailAddress` throughout the script, including `EmailAddress   = $user.EmailAddress` -> `EmailAddress   = $user.mail`